# Insert pdf between text

Tags: floats, pdfpages

I want to insert figure below into my document to a specified scale of 0.7 between text and I also want it captioned. If I use the figure environment it creates a whole page for itself(even after using `\begin{figure}[H]`. The figure is In a single page PDF.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
```

Comment: you have shown no code which makes it hard to answer but `\begin{figure}[H]\includegraphics[scale=0.7]{aaa.pdf}\caption{aaa}\end{figure}` should work

Comment: In a test run, wrap `\fbox` around `\includegraphics`, like so: `\fbox{\includegraphics[scale=0.7]{aaa.pdf}}`. It will draw a box around the picture. Any white area that you see within is part of the pdf, that you either have to remove by an external program, or by using the `viewport` and `clip` arguments of `\includegraphics`.

Comment: Remember that "a single page PDF" is still a full page. Reducing by 30% would still take up more than 70% of the text block, which necessarily puts it on a single page (to avoid straggling bits of text above/below.

Comment: Since you set the tag `pdfpages`: Do not use `\includepdf` if you want to put the picture into a `figure`-environment. Use `\includegraphics` instead.

Comment: @AndreasMatthias thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Your most likely issue here is that the image itself is too big to fit within the text block boundary, even though you scale it down to 70%. Options to remedy the situation:

1. Choose a smaller scale until the image fits within the page, or adjust the margins to allow some form of textual flow around it (rather than being set on a page by itself);
2. Trim enough excess whitespace around the image to reduce its ultimate size

As an example that highlights your issue, let's assume your image is `example-image-letter` (from [`mwe`](//ctan.org/pkg/mwe)):

[image]

In the above image, the page boundary forms part of the image.

Placement of the image is mostly impacted by the final image height. Including this at 70% scale into a document leaves you with an image that has a height of 11.5in x 0.7 ~ 8in. With the default `\textheight` of a document being less than that (550pt ~ 7.6in for a letter-sized document), there's no way you can fit a full page in between text on the same page. As such, any inclusion method (even with `[H]` from [`float`](//ctan.org/pkg/float)) will cause the image to spill over to the next page, or be set on a page-of-floats (on its own).

Follow remedy option (1) (a smaller scale value) to make it fit or adjust the text block margins using [`geometry`](//ctan.org/pkg/geometry). Here's an example using the former option:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx,float}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]

\begin{figure}[H]
  \centering
  \includegraphics[scale=0.4]{example-image-letter}
  \caption{A figure caption.}
\end{figure}

\lipsum[2]

\end{document}
```

For option (2), you can use the `bb` and `clip` option to trim off some excess whitespace from your image (assuming that it is actually smaller than a full page). Here's an example using that approach:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx,float}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]

\begin{figure}[H]
  \centering
  \includegraphics[scale=0.7,bb=1in 5in 7.5in 10in,clip]{example-image-letter}
  \caption{A figure caption.}
\end{figure}

\lipsum[2]

\end{document}
```

Using `bb=1in 5in 7.5in 10in` and `clip` I've trimmed `1in` from the left/right of the document, `5in` from the bottom and `1in` from the top (the default paper size is letter, which has dimensions 8.5in x 11in). The values for `bb=<llx> <lly> <urx> <ury>` represent the `l`ower `l`eft and `u`pper `r`ight `x`/`y` coordinates on the page.